# Cant SSH to Pi Zero - 'connection abort'

Tags: ssh, pi-zero, jessie-lite

Setting up SSH over wifi with new Raspberry Pi Zero. I installed an Edimax wifi adapter, ran `raspi-config` to enable ssh, and edited `/etc/network/interfaces` and `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` in the same way as I have done with 4 Raspberry Pi Model B+ units currently in my network.

The Zero boots up with a pingable wifi address (configured as static).

The Zero is refusing an SSH connection: when I attempt from Putty I immediately get:

`network error: software caused connection abort`

Tried the Putty connection from another windows host with the same result.  When I attempt from another pi (`ssh username@ip_address`) I get:

`Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer`.

The error is immediate, and happens every time. There are no firewall or router issues; these are all on one subnet (other SSH sessions to Pis are on wired network, not wifi).

I am sure SSH is enabled (`ps aux | grep sshd`) and listening on port 22 (`netstat -plant | grep :22`).

I can ping this new pi over wifi, but can't establish the SSH session. Is there some limitation to the Pi Zero I don't know about? Or problems with SSH over wifi?

The only thing different about this Pi (other than it's a zero) is that it only has access to the local network via wifi.

**EDIT:**
I have the latest JessieLite distribution 2017-03-02.

Comment: To rule out the obvious have you rebooted?

Comment: yes; I have only the one USB port so I have to swap out keyboard/edimax and reboot each time

Comment: Do you happened to have another device that using the same IP that is in conflict with your Pi zero's static IP?

Comment: No, using IP Scanner shows no conflicts. I did, however, have two different IP addresses on this pi associated with wlan0; this was because I had a static ip specified both in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcpcd.conf. Removed one of them and I was down to one IP, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you, and following the instructions in this [thread](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=133758&p=890820) worked for me.

so do

```
sudo rm /etc/ssh/ssh_host_*

sudo dpkg-reconfigure openssh-server
```

This will rebuild the ssh keys and config.  Hopefully it works for you as well.

Comment: fixed it for me.  This was so frustrating!

Answer (score 1):

As of the November 2016 release, Raspbian has the SSH server disabled by default. It can be enabled manually from the desktop or by `raspi-config`.

Comment: he said in his original post he enabled ssh via `raspi-config`

Answer (score 0):

If your Rpi partitions are stored on either a (micro)SD card and/or a USB memory stick, mount its boot partition on a computer and use the *touch* utility to create an empty file with a name **ssh**. Once done, execute *sync* before *unmount*ing the partition. Then, take it to your Rpi device to boot. Once booted, hopefully you should have no problem to SSH into your Rpi device.